# Search Engine in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, eclipse-jdt

I am developing a plugin to remove the sysout statements in an eclipse workspace. As part of this plugin I also want to provide the functionality to search and view the instances of sysout statements in eclipse search view. Is there a way to do this using the eclipse JDT API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model to modify your code.

To keep it abstract, you could have the user mark the expression to search for (and replace) in the outline view (in this case `System.out`). You can then get access to the selected `IMember` through the `ISelection` and use `SearchEngine` to find all references to it. After you have collected all the references you want to change you can use an `ASTParser` to get the AST for the source files. I would recommend to use `ASTRewrite` to do (and collect) the changes.

Here are two articles I found to be very helpfull:

- [Unleashing the Power of Refactoring](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html)
- [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine` instance.  In particular, you would be interested in calling the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchPattern, SearchParticipant[], IJavaSearchScope, SearchRequestor, IProgressMonitor)`.

Take a look at the Javadoc for that method.  You need to provide a proper `SearchPattern` for the thing you are looking for. I would create a pattern for the `System.out` and `System.err` references, rather than `PrintStream.println` references (since these may be legitimate).

You can specify the search scope, also.  So, it can be the entire workspace, a set of projects, or even the current selection.